# Run selfcontrol in the background

Tags: macos, selfcontrol

I use selfcontrol whilst working on my laptop.
Is there any way to have it running invisibly so I don't have to keep being reminded it is there?!
Would it be better to block the sites with a HOSTS file?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

SelfControl should continue to block the selected domains even after you quit the application. If it doesn't, you could try disabling SelfControl:

```
sudo sed -i '' '/# BEGIN SELFCONTROL/,/# END SELFCONTROL/d' /etc/hosts
sudo sed -i '' 's|<date>.*|<date>2010-01-01T01:01:01Z</date>|' /etc/SelfControl.lock
killall SelfControl; open -a SelfControl
```

Or try removing some of the support files:

```
rm /etc/SelfControl.lock ~/Library/Preferences/org.eyebeam.SelfControl.plist
```

You can use `/etc/hosts` by running `sudo nano /etc/hosts` in Terminal and adding lines like this to the end:

```
0.0.0.0 www.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 facebook.com
```

Then save the file by pressing control-x and y, and the changes should be applied within a few seconds.